# "Generate Random String" keyword in String Library of Robot Framework for assigning to variable

Tags: testing, random, automation, robotframework, browser-automation

I need to generate random number and assign it to the variable once to use it multiple times later. I found keyword `Generate Random String` but I don't know how to apply it for my case.

Comment: Why Generate Random String is not suitable?

Comment: Oh, I mean I don't know how to apply it. Sorry)

Comment: Okay, then what is your case? Can you post what you have tried so far? In general you just assing the output of that keyword to a variable and use that variable as usual. So `${random strig}    Generate Random String`

Comment: I want to create a user with random password, assign it to the variable and after log in with this password.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  String

*** test cases ***
login with random string
    ${password} =  Generate Random String  8  [NUMBERS]
    login to system  login  ${password}

*** Keywords ***
login to system    
    [arguments]  ${login}  ${password}
    log to console  \nattempting to log with login ${login} and password ${password}
```

and what you get when you execute it:

```
[MBP]$ pybot ts.txt
==============================================================================
Ts
==============================================================================
login with random string                                              .
attempting to log with login login and password 30865042
login with random string                                              | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ts                                                                    | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
[...]
```

another execution would generate another random number:

```
[MBP]$ pybot ts.txt
[...]
login with random string                                              .
attempting to log with login login and password 88780307
login with random string                                              | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```